# Unobtrusive JS: toggle element visibility with checkbox in a form

Tags: javascript, checkbox, toggle, visibility, unobtrusive-javascript

I am learning how to write unobtrusive Javascript, and I've been able to work most things out, but I'm having trouble with toggling an element's visibility on and off using a checkbox. Keep in mind that I am a designer first, programmer, oh 18th or so. In other words, I am a novice when it comes to programming. (Note: This form is for an endodontics firm referral form, hence the industry terms).

Also, please do not suggest JQuery; I know it exists, and I use it often. I want to learn how to actually do this in pure Javascript. Here are the important HTML snippets (this is created in asp.NET):

```
<ol>
<li>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Which of these procedures is required? (select at least one)<span class="required"> *</span></legend>
        <label id="procedure01"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkEndodonticProcedure01" GroupName="EndodonticProcedure" runat="server" />Consultation for evaluation of tooth</label>
        <label id="procedure02"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkEndodonticProcedure02" GroupName="EndodonticProcedure" runat="server" />Re-treatment of tooth</label>
        <label id="procedure03"><asp:CheckBox ID="chkEndodonticProcedure03" GroupName="EndodonticProcedure" runat="server" />Treatment of tooth</label>
    </fieldset>
    <ol id="consultation">
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblConsultationToothNumber" AssociatedControlID="txtConsultationToothNumber" runat="server">Consultation tooth number</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtConsultationToothNumber" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Do any of these conditions apply?</legend>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkToothCondition01" GroupName="ToothCondition" runat="server" />Vague toothache</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkToothCondition02" GroupName="ToothCondition" runat="server" />Pain, swelling</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkToothCondition03" GroupName="ToothCondition" runat="server" />Sensitivity to heat</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkToothCondition04" GroupName="ToothCondition" runat="server" />Sensitivity to cold</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkToothCondition05" GroupName="ToothCondition" runat="server" />Sensitivity to percussion</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkToothCondition06" GroupName="ToothCondition" runat="server" />Possible combined perio-endo lesion</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkToothCondition07" GroupName="ToothCondition" runat="server" />Suspected cracked tooth/root</label>
            </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="retreatment">
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRetreatmentToothNumber" AssociatedControlID="txtRetreatmentToothNumber" runat="server">Re-treatment tooth number</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtRetreatmentToothNumber" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblPreviousRCTDate" AssociatedControlID="txtPreviousRCTDate" runat="server">Date of previous RCT</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtPreviousRCTDate" CssClass="textbox datepicker" runat="server" />
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol id="treatment">
        <li>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTreatmentToothNumber" AssociatedControlID="txtTreatmentToothNumber" runat="server">Treatment tooth number</asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox id="txtTreatmentToothNumber" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>What is the reason for treatment? (check any that apply)</legend>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkTreatmentReason01" GroupName="TreatmentReason" runat="server" />Necessary for proper restoration</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkTreatmentReason02" GroupName="TreatmentReason" runat="server" />Pulp exposed and vital</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkTreatmentReason03" GroupName="TreatmentReason" runat="server" />Pulp exposed and non-vital</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkTreatmentReason04" GroupName="TreatmentReason" runat="server" />Tooth was opened and medicated</label>
                <label><asp:CheckBox ID="chkTreatmentReason05" GroupName="TreatmentReason" runat="server" />X-ray revealed radiolucency/pulpal involvement</label>
            </fieldset>
        </li>
        <li>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Is an X-ray included for revealed radiolucency/pulpal involvement?</legend>
                <label><asp:RadioButton ID="rdoXrayIncluded01" GroupName="XrayIncluded" runat="server" />Yes</label>
                <label><asp:RadioButton ID="rdoXrayIncluded02" GroupName="XrayIncluded" runat="server" />No</label>
            </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

Using unobtrusive Javascript, I grab the form ID ("referralform"), create two arrays to contain the related element IDs, hide the elements I want turned off with a CSS class, and then apply the onclick event to apply the CSS class that reveals the elements:

```
function prepareAccordion()
{
if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName)
{
    if (document.getElementById("referralform"))
    {
        var accordionids = new Array();
        accordionids[0] = document.getElementById("minorparent");
        accordionids[1] = document.getElementById("consultation");
        accordionids[2] = document.getElementById("retreatment");
        accordionids[3] = document.getElementById("treatment");

        var revealids = new Array();
        revealids[0] = document.getElementById("minorYes");
        revealids[1] = document.getElementById("minorNo");
        revealids[2] = document.getElementById("procedure01");
        revealids[3] = document.getElementById("procedure02");
        revealids[4] = document.getElementById("procedure03");

        for (var i = 0; i < accordionids.length; i++)
        {
            accordionids[i].className = "accordion-collapsed";
        }

        revealids[0].onclick = function revealAccordion()
        {
            accordionids[0].className = "accordion-revealed";
        }

        revealids[1].onclick = function revealAccordion()
        {
            accordionids[0].className = "accordion-collapsed";
        }

        x = 0;
        revealids[2].onclick = function revealAccordion()
        {
            if (x == 0)
            {
                accordionids[1].className = "accordion-revealed";
                x++;
            }
            else
            {
                accordionids[1].className = "accordion-collapsed";
                x--;
            }
        }

        y = 0;
        revealids[3].onclick = function revealAccordion()
        {
            if (y == 0)
            {
                accordionids[2].className = "accordion-revealed";
                y = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                accordionids[2].className = "accordion-collapsed";
                y = 0;
            }
        }

        z = 0;
        revealids[4].onclick = function revealAccordion()
        {
            if (z == 0)
            {
                accordionids[3].className = "accordion-revealed";
                z = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                accordionids[3].className = "accordion-collapsed";
                z = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
}

function addLoadEvent(func)
{
var oldonload = window.onload;
if (typeof window.onload != 'function')
{
    window.onload = func;
}
else
{
    window.onload = function ()
    {
        if (oldonload)
        {
            oldonload();
        }
        func();
    }
}
}

addLoadEvent(prepareAccordion);
```

There is likely a much better way to create "on/off" toggle settings for checkboxes than using "1" and "0" and flipping between them, but again, I'm not a programmer. The issue is that when applying the flip between "1" and "0", the onclick event only works when directly clicking within the checkbox, and not on the label. The onclick works fine when applied to a radio button's label, so it must be the flip between "1" and "0" that is throwing something off.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do — and, in fact what I do for my employer's site — is to mark page elements with a class, "toggleOnSwitch" (I tend to use irritating long names like that).  The element will then also have a couple of "data-" attributes: "data-switch", containing the "id" value for the checkbox or radio button or `<option>` element that controls the toggling; "data-toggle-class", containing the class to toggle on and off (like, "hidden" or "inactive" or whatever); and maybe one or two others I'm forgetting.

The unobtrusive JavaScript looks for that class, and then for each toggled element it sets up event handlers on the switch element (the checkbox, in your case). The event handlers do the work of adding/removing the class from the toggled element.

It's a little more complicated than that if you want to toggle on radio buttons, because when one radio button switches *on*, all its friends switch *off*, so the handler has to know to trigger the toggle handlers on all the other radio buttons with the same name, in case they also control page element visibility (or whatever the added/removed class does).  I also coded mine so that if the "data-switch" value starts with a "!", like "!toggleCheckbox", then that means to reverse the sense of the toggle. That's handy when a particular checkbox switches one thing off at the same time it switches another thing on.